# I try to put a tree in vector in in-order way

Tags: c++, vector, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

Why is it just pushing last element??? I have made the last element nullptr so the leaf above that should become the last node right? Why is not working

```
void ans(TreeNode* root)
        {
            if(root->left!=nullptr)
            {
                ans(root->left);
                if(root->left==nullptr)
                {
                    cout<<"fdfef";
                }
            }
            if(root->right!=nullptr)
            {
                ans(root->right);
            }
            if(root->left==nullptr&&root->right==nullptr)
            {
                cout<<root->val;;
                q.push_back(root->val);
                root=nullptr;
                return;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

> ... so the leaf above that should become the last node right?

No, `root` is a local, separate variable, and assigning to that variable does not affect that pointer that was passed **by value**.

The solution is to pass **by reference**:

```cpp
void ans(TreeNode* &root)
//                 ^^
```